# Receiving data from RS232(com)

Tags: c#, c++, c, com, serial-port

I want to write an app that receive data from RS232(sometimes using usb connector) port using C/C#.

I have searched the web but found nothing. Do u have anything interesting? Articles, tutorials, tips, code snippets, everything is very much appreciated.

I have got transmission protocol, but have no idea how to read data from rs232. 
Can I read/write data asynchronously?

Comment: The solution for this should be pretty similar for C and C++, but _way_ different for C#. You should really pick one language and stick with it.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Windows. Then the answer to your question is msdn.com.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg well I know both so it doesnt really matter for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this really great tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8605/Serial-Communication-using-C-and-Whidbey . It offers not only a whole small project but it also explains the basics of serial communication.

As for the USB-to-Serial-connector or real RS232 - it doesn't really matter because Windows recognizes both as a COM port. If you open your Device manager, in the **Ports(COM & LPT)** section you will be able to see both.